# Location sensor not giving location on ios when enabled on Delphi

Tags: ios, delphi, location

I'm developing an app for ios and android on Delphi. I have a location sensor that is active. It works without problems on android but on ios it does not work. The program never goes into onlocationchanged event of the sensor location so I cannot get the location of the device. Do I forget anything about uses or something to make the sensor work on ios?

Thank you.

Comment: Known issue on Delphi 10.3 Rio: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21834. If you don't have a login for the Quality Portal, please create one. There is a workaround in the description of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Dave! I have to visit the quality portal more...

The solution is:

> The problem can be worked around by copying the unit to the project
>   folder, and commenting out line 151 (the MethodName attribute for
>   locationManagerDidUpdateLocations)